# Passport req.logout() function not found by the compiler

Tags: node.js, typescript, xmlhttprequest, logout, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth 2.0 with Passport in my TypeScript NodeJs app. I managed to log the user in, but I'm stuck at the logout part because my compiler does not seem to recognize the logout() method (logOut did not work either).

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res){
    req.logout();
});
```

> Error: Property 'logout' does not exist on type 'Request<{}, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)

I also want to mention that I have encountered some other issues while trying to access properties of the req parameter when giving it the type *Request*, so I gave up on the type.
I think it is because of TypeScript, but I don't want to write my app using JS, so any advice on that would be appreciated.

My package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.28",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^14.3.2",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-passport-logout": "^0.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.8",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": false,
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own type:

```
type LogoutRequest = Request & { logout: ()=>void }
router.get("/logout", function (req:LogoutRequest, res) {
  req.logout()
  res.redirect("/")
})
```